# MinGW or Cygwin for Python development on Windows?

Tags: python, cygwin, mingw

I am using vanilla Python 3.x on Windows, using Pycharm as IDE.

Although this is working; I need to install different packages and modules; and I did notice that windows has no pip, from what I can tell.

I am familiar with Python on Linux, and most of the time it is a matter of use pip to install new packages and modules for Python; but on windows it seems more daunting and complex.

I was told to use either MinGW or Cygwin, so I can be in a full unix environment, using terminal commands that I am used to, and the unix console; althought I do not get the difference, related to python.

The code that I write, will be eventually deployed on Linux, OSX and Windows; would matter if I use CygWin or MinGW? If this is too much of a trouble, it is probably easier to just install Ubuntu as VM and work there; but I am hoping that I can do the same on a standard W10 machine.

Comment: If you wait long enough... the problem might [resolve itself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/faq)!

Comment: This is outstanding! You should post it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In Pycharms you also have access to a terminal in which you can run `pip install` on. [Check this link out](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/working-with-embedded-local-terminal.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment with this if I had the rep to do so, as it fails to stay within the scope of your question. I'm guessing you've heard of [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) but using `conda` and many commands associated with it, you can manage packages and virtual environments, etc. If the problem is Python on Windows (as opposed to Python in a Linux environment on Windows), I recommend checking it out, if you haven't heard of it already!